# Is this fact true $T:X \longrightarrow Y$ linear and bounded operator with $X$ reflexive then $T$ is compact?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I wonder if this fact is true.

I consider a linear operator $T:X \longrightarrow Y$, with $Y$ and $X$ two normed spaces. 
I suppose that $X$ is a reflexive space and that $T$ a bounded operator.

Is it true that $T$ is necessary a compact operator? If yes, how can I prove it?

Thank you!

Comment: Is every identity operator compact?

Comment: No, if $X$  has not finite dimension....So the answer is no...thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. By the way, the statement does hold for certain $X$ and $Y$. See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/218284/proof-of-the-pitts-theorem) for example.