# No bounded linear surjectivity from $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$ to $\ell^1(\mathbb{N})$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, lp-spaces, baire-category

I would like to show that a bounded linear operator $T: \ell^2(\mathbb{N}) \rightarrow \ell^1(\mathbb{N})$ cannot be surjective.

If we assume surjectivity, then by the Open Mapping Theorem, $T$ is an open map, i.e. for every open $O \subset \ell^2(\mathbb{N})$, its image $T(O)$ is open in $\ell^1(\mathbb{N})$.

Is it then possible to contradict Baire's Theorem by constructing a sequence of open dense subsets of $\ell^1(\mathbb{N})$, whose intersection is not dense?

Any help pointing me into the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

If $T: \ell^2(\mathbb N) \to \ell^1(\mathbb N)$ is a surjective bounded linear transformation, then the adjoint $T^*: (\ell^1(\mathbb N))^* \to (\ell^2(\mathbb N))^*$ is an isomorphism onto a closed linear subspace.
But $(\ell^1(\mathbb N)^* \sim \ell^\infty(\mathbb N)$ is not separable, while $\ell^2(\mathbb N)^* \sim \ell^2(\mathbb N)$ is separable, and so is any of its subspaces.

Comment: Thanks. I know how to show the separability of $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$ and the non-separability of $\ell^\infty(\mathbb{N})$. I can also show that $T^*$ is injective. But how do I conclude that it is an isomorphism?

Comment: Closed Range Theorem.

Answer (score 2):

As $\ell_2$ is reflexive, every operator $T\colon \ell_2\to \ell_1$ is weakly compact. Thus the unit ball $B_{\ell_1}$ of $\ell_1$ would be weakly compact but the canonical basis of $\ell_1$ is in $B_{\ell_1}$ but it does not have a weakly convergent subsequence.

Actually, by [Pitt's theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/218284/proof-of-the-pitts-theorem), every bounded linear operator $T\colon \ell_2\to\ell_1$ is compact.