# isomorphism between $\ell^2$ and $\ell^3$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $p\in(1,\infty)$ a $\ell^p$ be the space of sequences $x=\{x_n\}$ such that $\|x\|^p=\sum_{n=1}^\infty |x_n|^p<\infty$. Are spaces $\ell^2$ and $\ell^3$ linearly isomorphic (as normed spaces) ?

Comment: isomorphic as what?

Comment: As normed spaces, they are not isomorphic: $\ell^2$ satisfies the parallelogram identity while $\ell^p$ does not if $p\ne 2$.

Comment: @Berci Parllelogram identity is not preserved by isomorphisms. I suppose you wanted to say that the spaces are not  isometrically isomorphic.

Comment: Yes, that's what I wanted to mean.

Comment: They are homeomorphic as topological spaces. (All separable locally convex metrisable TVS's are, but this special case is simpler.)

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, thanks, I corrected my question.

Comment: @Berci your comment should be an answer in my opinion

Comment: These two spaces are not linearly homeomorphic.  There is no bi-continuous linear bijection between them. Reference: Lindenstrauss & Tzafriri I ... https://www.amazon.com/Classical-Banach-Spaces-Ergebnisse-Grenzgebiete/dp/3540080724/

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/218284/proof-of-pitts-theorem